# Error in libcloud and vsphere integration

Tags: vsphere, libcloud, pysphere

I am using libcloud 1.2.1 with pysphere 0.1.7. I am getting the below error when trying to connect to the ESXi host.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/libcloud/compute/drivers/vsphere.py", line 152, in init
port=port, url=url)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/libcloud/common/base.py", line 1177, in init
self.connection = self.connectionCls(args, *conn_kwargs)
TypeError: init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'retry_delay'
```

I am using the below commands to connect to the host.

```
from libcloud.compute.types import Provider
from libcloud.compute.providers import get_driver
vsphere = get_driver(Provider.VSPHERE)
driver = vsphere(host='',username='username',password='password')
```

I can do this using pysphere only but not with libcloud. Tried looking on the internet and changing the content of the libraries but in vain. Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in v1.5.0<, there is a committed fix. You can apply the patch manually using [git am](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am): https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/apache/libcloud/pull/967.patch

Wait for v1.6.0, or install directly from GitHub trunk

```
pip install git+https://github.com/apache/libcloud.git@trunk#egg=apache-libcloud
```